# Display multidimensional array in a customize way

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array and it is like this:

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [open] => 05.00 PM
            [close] => 04.00 PM
            [state] => 0
        )

    [Tuesday] => Array
        (
            [open] => 
            [close] => 
            [state] => 1
        )

    [Wednesday] => Array
        (
            [open] => 03.00 AM
            [close] => 06.00 PM
            [state] => 0
        )

    [Thursday] => Array
        (
            [open] => 
            [close] => 
            [state] => 1
        )

    [Friday] => Array
        (
            [open] => 05.00 PM
            [close] => 03.00 PM
            [state] => 0
        )

    [Saturday] => Array
        (
            [open] => 05.00 PM
            [close] => 06.00 PM
            [state] => 0
        )

    [Sunday] => Array
        (
            [open] => 
            [close] => 
            [state] => 1
        )

)
```

Using this array I want to create output like this:

```
Monday       - 05.00 PM - 04.00 PM
Tuesday      - Closed
Wednesday    - 03.00 AM - 06.00 PM
Thursday     - Closed
Friday       - 05.00 PM - 03.00 PM
Saturday     - 05.00 PM - 06.00 PM
Sunday       - Closed
```

I tried it with 2 foreach loops, but I couldn't get it to show the expected output.

```
foreach ($result as $days => $values) {
    echo "$days";
    foreach ($values as $k) {
        echo " - $k";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Its output is similar to this:

```
Monday - 05.00 PM - 04.00 PM - 0
Tuesday - - - 1
Wednesday - 03.00 AM - 06.00 PM - 0
Thursday - - - 1
Friday - 05.00 PM - 03.00 PM - 0
Saturday - 05.00 PM - 06.00 PM - 0
Sunday - - - 1
```

Can anybody tell me how can I figure this out?

**NOTE:** if `state = 0` it doesn't need to display and `state = 1` it should be `Closed`

Comment: 1) You don't need a second `foreach`. You only want a specific number of values from the sub-array, and you also know their keys. Just access them directly. 2) Obviously you need an `if` statement to produce output according to the `state`. Put one in.

Comment: If you want to echo the value of $days only, you don't need to put quotation marks around it.

Answer (score 2):

Do the foreach loop like that:

```
foreach ($result as $days => $values) {
    echo $days." - ";
    echo $values["state"] ? "Closed" : $values["open"]." - ".$values["close"];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check `state` index exist(1) or not(0) like: `if ($values['state'])`

Try this one:

```
foreach ($result as $days => $values) {
    echo "$days";
    if ($values['state']) {
        echo " - Closed";
    } else {
        echo ": ".$values['open']." - ".$values['close'];
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: but its output like this - `Monday - 05.00 PM - 04.00 PM - 0
Tuesday - Closed
Wednesday - 03.00 AM - 06.00 PM - 0
Thursday - Closed
Friday - 05.00 PM - 03.00 PM - 0
Saturday - 05.00 PM - 06.00 PM - 0
Sunday - Closed`

Comment: @TNK Oo yes, i missed. This issue about foreach cause of loop all index. I removed. You dont need `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

Do foreach loop with html table to get currect aligned line

```
$data = "<table >";
foreach($result as $day=>$value) {
    if($value["state"]==1) {
        $value = "<td colspan='3'> Closed </td>";   
    } else {
        $value = "<td> $value[open] </td><td> - </td><td> $value[close] </td>";;
    }

    $data .= "<tr><td> $day </td><td> - </td> $value</tr>";
}
$data .= "</table>";

echo $data;
```